# Scheme - Deriviative using table

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to get the derivative in scheme using the code below. Would anyone be able to tell me where I am going wrong? I have been trying to figure it out for a while now.

```
(define d3
  (λ (e)
    (cond ((number? e) 0)
      ((equal? e 'x) 1)
      (else
       ;; We handle only BINARY ops here, and only + and *
       (let ((op (car e)) (args (cdr e)))
         (apply (lookup op d-op-table) args))))))


(define d-op-table
  (list(list '+ (λ (u v) (+ (d3 u) (d3 v))))
       (list '+ (λ (u1 v1)
             (list '(* u1 (d v1)))(list '(* (d u1) v1))))))

(define lookup
  (λ (op table)
    (if (equal? op (caar table))
    (cadar table)
    (lookup op (cdr table)))))
```

When I run the function, I get the following error. I input, (d3 '(* 2 x)).

```
    caar: contract violation
  expected: (cons/c pair? any/c)
  given: '()
```

Comment: what would be the value of `(cadr '(2))`? You are calling `cadr` in your function `d2`.

Comment: That should just return 0. I get similar when trying, (d2 '(* 2 x))

Comment: should it or does it?

Comment: Where are the definitions of `d1` and `d`? `(d2 '(0))` is obviously not supported, but `(d2 0) ; ==> 0` just fine. `(d2 '(* 2 x))` not so beacuse your `d-op-table` doesn't support `*` so it fails. Thus your code is littered with obvious bugs.

Comment: Apologies, updated code. Had copied over the wrong information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lookup table is incorrect, sometimes you evaluate expressions but others you just quote them, without evaluating them. For example, `'(* u1 (d v1))` will just evaluate to `'(* u1 (d v1))`, the derivate is not actually computed! The multiplication case looks particularly bad, it doesn't even have the proper search key `*`.

This is closer to what you intended, notice that you need more work to actually detect which expressions can be simplified - for instance: `(* 0 x)` is `0`, but it should be enough to get you started:

```
(define d-op-table
  (list (list '+ (λ (u v) (list '+ (d3 u) (d3 v))))
        (list '* (λ (u v)
                   (list '+
                         (list '* u (d3 v))
                         (list '* (d3 u) v))))))
```

Now your example works:

```
(d3 '(* 2 x))
=> '(+ (* 2 1) (* 0 x))
```

If you want to write a truly useful differentiation procedure, better take a look at [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_idx_2046).